# Result of expression '$.cookie' [undefined] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

Hi all in my mobile  application to pass variable in between various pages without ajax I am using cookie. I am setting cookie like :

```
 $.cookie("userName", userName, { path: '/' });
```

in js file and in in another html file I am accessing it as:

```
$.cookie('userName');
```

But I got error as:

```
Result of expression '$.cookie' [undefined] is not a function
```

I have one js file for cookie as: `jquery.cookie.js`  it contains following code:

```
/*jshint eqnull:true */
/*!
* jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.1
* https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
*
 * Copyright 2011, Klaus Hartl
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/GPL-2.0
 */
(function($, document) {

var pluses = /\+/g;
function raw(s) {
    return s;
}
function decoded(s) {
    return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
}

$.cookie = function(key, value, options) {

    // key and at least value given, set cookie...
    if (arguments.length > 1 && (!/Object/.test(Object.prototype.toString.call(value)) || value == null)) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.cookie.defaults, options);

        if (value == null) {
            options.expires = -1;
        }

        if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
            var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
            t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
        }

        value = String(value);

        return (document.cookie = [
            encodeURIComponent(key), '=', options.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
            options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
            options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
            options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
            options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
        ].join(''));
    }

    // key and possibly options given, get cookie...
    options = value || $.cookie.defaults || {};
    var decode = options.raw ? raw : decoded;
    var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
    for (var i = 0, parts; (parts = cookies[i] && cookies[i].split('=')); i++) {
        if (decode(parts.shift()) === key) {
            return decode(parts.join('='));
        }
    }
    return null;
};

  $.cookie.defaults = {};

   })(jQuery, document);
```

I had imported above js file in my html file also. I had also tried with `setCookie('userName', 'userName', 1);`
why is it so? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `jquery.cookie.js` is actually included, and that it's included *before* you call `$.cookie()`.

Comment: It looks like it. I think the important thing is to make sure it is loaded *before* you call `$.cookie()`.

Comment: Yes it is imported properly and in side head tag.

Comment: Yes, but are you sure you calling `$.cookie()` *after* it has been loaded? Is this happening in a JavaScript file included *before* you include `jquery.cookie.js`? Are you sure the page has fully loaded before you are executing your own JavaScript?

Comment: @ Edd Yes it was import issue by mistake I was importing another file. Now it is working. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 2):

Check in your console If `jquery.cookie.js` is loaded without errors.

You can find information about opening the console in your browser in [this Webmasters.SE question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have imported jquery.cookie.js correctly and try to access jquery function when they're ready

```
$(function(){

$.cookie('userName');

})
```

or

```
$(document.ready(function(){
$.cookie('userName');

}));
```

Comment: I had tried both option as you suggested still got same error. Please take look at my jquery.cookie.js file. Is this file is correct?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. make sure **didn't call jquery-1.9.0.min.js lib again** *after* jquery.cookie.js.

web pages usually have master and detail page. maybe you refrence to Jquery library again in detail page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 if (typeof $.cookie("user-popup") == "undefined") {}
```

you can check with this to check Cookie value is available or not